# getting leading space in the string variables stored in string array

Tags: java

I have a parameter which contains the following value

```
 String filesTypesallowed =".xsl,.xslx ";
```

Now i have pass this parameter in another method named filterfile as shown below now as you can see that in the method i am getting the fileName as one of the parameter in which i must be getting any file name lets say it mite be abc.csv file , so what i have to do is that check whether the file that i am getting inside the parameter fileName ends with extension .xlsx or .xls then in that case i have to return the file name but other than that extension lets say i have got a file with an extension like ert.csv then in that case i have to return simply null

please advise how to achieve this what i have tried is shown below creating a seprate method

```
private String filterfile(String fileName , String filesTypesallowed) {
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.split(",");
    if (Arrays.asList(allowedExtensions).contains(extension)) {
        return fileName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

but the above method is not working when the files with .xslx extensions is being passed as upon debuging i can see that the value allowedExtensions array is as shown below

```
allowedExtensions = .xls,  .xlsx
```

so as you can see there is space in .xlsx which is creating a problem please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: Leading and trailing spaces can be removed using `trim()`. You can use this function.

Comment: @John That is possible with Strings, but that would force making a `for` loop and `trim()` on each element of the array, which would probably not simplify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `allowedExtensions = .xls,  .xlsx` will give you `space.xlsx` and not `.xlsx` you should split with `\\s+,\\s+` to avoid extra spaces between extensions.

Comment: I did not even know that `split` accepts regex. +1 for saving a useless step.

Answer (score 3):

You could ignore all spaces just before splitting into an array with the following statement:

```
String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(",");
```

[TAsk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847331/1734119) saves you a statement and one String instantiation by using a regex inside the `split` method, which is great!

```
String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.split("\\s+,\\s+");
```

To avoid the error [Codebender highlighted in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847357/1734119), you could even combine this with a `trim()` to remove any space at the beginning or end of you original String:

```
String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.trim().split("\\s+,\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Before splitting the `filesTypesallowed` String remove all whitespace from it using `filesTypesallowed.replaceAll("\\s","");`

```
private String filterfile(String fileName , String filesTypesallowed) {
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));

    String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.replaceAll("\\s","").split(",");

    if (Arrays.asList(allowedExtensions).contains(extension)) {
        return fileName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no space before `.xlsx`. `String.split()` doesn't work in that way.

It's not working because in your string `filesTypesallowed`, there is a space at the end.

Change your string to  `String filesTypesallowed =".xsl,.xslx";` and it should work.

Comment: I missed the ending space. Good catch!